# Order of array elements sent in AJAX server response seems changed on traversing at client side

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have return the following json response from my server side -

```
echo json_encode(array("result"=>"success", "networks" => $adNetworkListFinal));
```

Where, taking an example, $adNetworkListFinal has the following value -

```
Array
(
    [-3] => Native Test
    [143] => conf native template
    [142] => test native
)
```

*Note - index -3 is the first one. Yes, it is a negative integer index, which I am having to use here.*

But, in the client side, when I traverse the response with a .each(), I get the item with index `-3` at last -

**Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: posturl,
    data : data,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){


        if (msg.result == "success")
        {   
            $.each(msg.networks,function(key,val)
            {
                console.log("check "+key);                  
            });

        }
    });
```

**Output**

```
check 142

check 143

check -3
```

I am not sure what is causing the change in order (item indexed -3 is getting accessed at last), and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays cannot have negative indexes so you are creating a JSON object (and hence a JavaScript object).

JSON and JavaScript objects are *unordered* so you get the properties back in whatever order the JS engine cares to store them in.

Since the values are numerical, you can pull them into an array (as values, not indexes) and sort them before using them to access the values of the original object.

Comment: Since my array might also contain an index -1 (which needs to appear at the end) :D, I know it is dirty. Hence, sorting at client side is not an option here. But your answer clicked another approach in my mind - I think passing another array with the desired order of indexes (as values of the array) in my AJAX response can solve the issue. In the client side, I will refer this array to traverse the original array.